# read actionlistener in JFrame from JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, actionlistener

in the code below i want to change the panel depending on the event of buttons situated in Panel1 and Panel2 
.The Panel1 only contains a button the same goes for Panel2

```
public class Window extends JFrame {
 public window(){
this.setTitle("CardLayout");
this.setSize(300, 120);
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 Panel2 p2 = new Panel2();
 Panel1 p1 = new Panel1();
 this.getContentPane().add(p1);
 this.setVisible(true);
p2.getButton2().addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Panel1 p1 = new Panel1();
                getContentPane().removeAll();
                getContentPane().add(p1);
                getContentPane().validate();
                getContentPane().repaint();
                System.out.println("change to panel1");

    }   
});
p1.getButton1().addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Panel2 p2 = new Panel2();
                getContentPane().removeAll();
                getContentPane().add(p2);
                getContentPane().validate();
                getContentPane().repaint();
                System.out.println("change to panel2");


    }   
});
```

} 
}

Comment: And why don't you just use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: Why recreate a new panel when pressing the button? Use the same panels.

Comment: What seems to be the problem?  I'm wondering what your question is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might be looking for this

```
public class testframe extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
String panel = "Card with JButtons";
String panel2 = "Card with JTextField";
JPanel cards = new JPanel();
JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public testframe() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    setContentPane(contentPane);  

    cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    card1 = new JPanel();
    card2 = new JPanel();

    JButton b1 = new JButton("button 1");
    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
            cl.show(cards, panel2); 
        }
    });
    card1.add(b1);

    JButton b2 = new JButton("button 2");
    b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
            cl.show(cards, panel);
        }
    });
    card2.add(b2);      

    cards.add(card1, panel);
    cards.add(card2, panel2);



    contentPane.add(cards);

}
```

if that is so, this will be helpful as well: [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you switch panels, you are creating and adding new JPanel objects, without adding an ActionListener to the buttons within those new JPanel instances. So either reuse your old JPanels within the ActionListeners you create here where you do the following, with the changes here to add the final keyword to p2 and p1:

```
final Panel2 p2 = new Panel2();
final Panel1 p1 = new Panel1();
this.getContentPane().add(p1);
this.setVisible(true);
```

and in the individual ActionListeners you create, remove the lines of:

Panel1 p1 = new Panel1();

and

Panel2 p2 = new Panel2();

Removing those lines will cause p1 and p2 to refer to the original p1 and p2 panels. Although you should probably just use the card layout.

Comment: ok i think  it's a good solution to use card layout but the thing that i've don't understand is that in my code above why the first event worked (: b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() )  and not the second (:p1.getButton1().addActionListener(new ActionListener())

Comment: Yes, card layout looks to be what you're going for. Your first event worked because on your first initial panel you added an ActionListener to it's JButton. Then, within that ActionListener's method, you remove the panel that has a JButton that has an ActionListener, and you replace with it a new panel, which has a new Button, that you did not add an ActionListener to yet. That's what I'm trying to describe in my first paragraph. You only added an ActionListener to the JButtons within your first initial instances of your panels, p2 and p1, and not subsequent new JButtons in your new panels.